# Which open source platform is good for a private/hybrid cloud?

Tags: cloud, private, hybrid, eucalyptus

I'm working on building a private cloud, and we've been considering Eucalyptus and OpenNebula.
Are there any other good open source platform available for building a private/hybrid cloud?
Between Eucalyptus and OpenNebula, which one do you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

[Abiquo](http://www.abiquo.com/) is commercial, but offers an open source "community edition" under GPL3. However, I don't know what features are in and what's not in the open source edition versus the enterprise edition.

[Nimbula](http://nimbula.com/) is new, but looks very interesting. I heard a rumor of them doing open source, but could be wrong.

[OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) holds a lot of promise. There are a number of contributors, including the primaries RackSpace and NASA.

That's three potential Infrastructure-as-a-Service right off the top of my head.

However, if you are also looking into Platform-as-a-Service tools to ride on top of the infrastructure, you have other considerations. Under the PaaS umbrella you'll find tools and services for virtualizing applications, building applications that auto-scale up and down and have automatic failover reliability, storage solutions ala Amazon S3, simplified application and service management across many servers, etc.

OpenStack offers a storage solution ala Amazon S3.

[Appistry CloudIQ Platform](http://www.appistry.com) offers a free community edition version which can be used in production (distributed storage ala S3, distributed execution engine for building cloud applications, distributed memory cache, application/service management and virtualization) .

[GigaSpaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com/) offers open source versions of some of their distributed tools and services (distributed memory cache, distributed execution engine for building cloud applications)

I'm sure there are more, but again, off the top of my head. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

One more:
http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud

Comment: This is really just Eucalyptus behind the scenes.  They also plan on offering OpenStack in 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.openqrm.com/ is my choice. It can manage bare metal or virtual environments and has a  nice "cloud" plugin for multi-user resource provisioning. Since 4.6 (mid 2010) you could use the same get up to provision Win/Lin on bare metal locally or move the same vm to AWS.

You could use http://www.enomaly.com/ 's Elastic Cloud Platform - it does not have the bare metal support that OpenQRM has, but with ECP you can sell/buy capacity off of a end-user market, spotcloud. #1 problem with ECP is that it seem's Enomaly has abandoned its open source efforts.